# How get options from a PHP REST WEBSERVICE

Tags: php, ajax, web-services, phonegap

i'm get to populate a select tag with ajax from a rest webservice(that I dont have  the code, my profesor just give the url) but i'm trying and didn't work

my ajax code:

```
<form method="GET" type="REST">  
    <select name="campus" id="campus" type="option" value="codCampus">

            <script type="text/javascript">  
               $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json", // i try put option and also didnt work
                url: "http://191.252.96.136/plesk-site-preview/pimsorocaba.com.br/191.252.96.136/webpim.php?tipo=option&tabela=Campus&campo=campus&valor=codCampus",
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
              });
            </script>
    </select>

    <select name="periodo" id="periodo" type="option" value="codPeriodo">
    </select>

    <select name="curso" id="curso" type="option" value="codCurso">
    </select>         
</form>
```

Comment: i'm sorry for my really bad english

Answer (score 0):

In the url that you requested data, don't have a headers, so you need to install a chrome extension. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

My advice to you, ask for your professor to include a cors in api. So follow the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="GET" type="REST">
  <select name="campus" id="campus" type="option" value="codCampus">


  </select>

  <select name="periodo" id="periodo" type="option" value="codPeriodo">
  </select>

  <select name="curso" id="curso" type="option" value="codCurso">
  </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://191.252.96.136/plesk-site-preview/pimsorocaba.com.br/191.252.96.136/webpim.php?tipo=option&tabela=Campus&campo=campus&valor=codCampus",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#campus').html(response)
    },

  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks man, i'm gone do It that, but with This extention  Works an phonegap app to? And the 'response' Will be the options?